# Table cell break word won't shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I often use this HTML/CSS structure to create a mobile-friendly table (It changes layout on narrow (mobile) screens; something very lacking in CSS frameworks) and it has been quite reliable for me. In my main project I have several tables with lots of data and varying widths.

If you open this codepen and change the view to 'debug' you can shrink the page width. Past 500px the table layout will change. The thead is hidden, secondary labels are shown and the tds are set to display: flex. (I like to use the responsive device toolbar in the inspector).

Under the table is a more simple set of divs, that behaves the way I want the divs inside the TD to work, but for some reason, the second div inside the td stops shrinking at a certain point. I have tried different combinations of word-wrap and white space but so far no luck. Seems the difference has to do with these divs being inside a table...

Is this just a limitation of tables or is there a way I can make the right div shrink like the second example?

Thanks!

https://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/qoypYJ

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="td-label">number</div>
                <div>this is the first one</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="td-label">number</div>
                <div>this is the second one</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="cont">
    <div class="in1">oneoneone oneone one oneoneoneoneoneon</div>
    <div class="in2">two two twotwotwo twotwotwotwo</div>
</div>

table { width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; margin: 0 0 10px; }
th { padding: 10px 10px 0; text-align: left; }
td { padding: 10px;  border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.td-label {
    display: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
    thead { display: none; }
    td {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
        > div:not(.td-label) {
            word-wrap: break-word;
            min-width: 1px;
        }
    }
    .td-label {
        display: table;
    }
}

.cont {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    > div {
        &:first-of-type {
            min-width: 100px;
            max-width: 50px;
        }
        min-width: 1px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to set the table width to 100%, add a min-width to the second div, and set display: table on the second div. I updated the pen and code above to reflect.